# NetBeans 7.1.2 will not uninstall properly on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, netbeans

I don't usually have issues adding or removing different versions of NB so i was supprised to run into this. On my Windows 7 Box when I removed NB and canceled the installation since i decided it would be good to first back up my project files, the installer stopped working correctly since. Basically in my Control Panel>Programs>Programs and Features when I attempt to uninstall a popup window that says NetBeans IDE Installer pops up with message "configuring the uninstaller" and the progress bar goes to 100 percent and disappears. So I tried manually uninstalling by removing my .nbi and .netbeans directory and deleting the Program Files/NetBeans 7.1.2 and Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2 folders and did a reinstall. Now in my Control Panel Programs Programs and Features i have two entries of glassfish and netbeans. when i try using either of them I get the same behavior i originally did which is the popup followed by no activity. I imagine if i do another manual reinstall i'll end up with a ton of entries in my Program and Features list. I've been going at this for a couple of hours now and any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing everything from netbeans in program files. Then if you try to uninstall again, it will work.
I have had the same problem and solved it as such.